# How shall I modify my trigger so that I can get the total_employees according to their departments?

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

tables are given below.

```
CREATE TABLE `departments` (
department_id INT(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
department_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
total_employees INT(4),
PRIMARY KEY (department_id),
UNIQUE (department_name));

CREATE TABLE `employees` (
employee_id INT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
employee_email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
employee_first_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
employee_last_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
department_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (employee_id),
UNIQUE (employee_email),
FOREIGN KEY (department_name)
    REFERENCES departments (department_name)
    ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

this is the trigger, I want it to be showing the sum of total employees in each department.

```
delimiter $$
create trigger department_wise_total_employee_counting
after insert on employees 
for each row begin update departments set total_employees=total_employees+1
where department_id=department_id; end$$ delimiter ;

INSERT INTO `departments` 
VALUES 
(1,'HRM',0),(2,'Accounting',0);
INSERT INTO `employees` 
VALUES 
(1,'bh@gmail.com','A','B','HRM'),
(2,'ak@gmail.com','C','D','HRM'),
(3,'mr@gmail.com','E','F','HRM'), 
(4,'pr@gmail.com','G','H','Accounting');
```

On running the following query :

```
select * from departments;
```

I'm getting this output, which just gives the total employee count rather than the total for each department.
[image]

I am trying to get total_employees=3 for HRM and total_employees=1 for Accounting. 
Would appreciate any sort of suggestions.

Comment: use mysql view instead of trigger

Comment: @TamilSelvanC would be great if you could demonstrate your idea a bit.

Comment: You shouldn't store stuff you can easily calculate - also you would need a delete trigger if someone leaves and an update trigger if employee changes department.

Comment: In an insert trigger I would expect to see reference to NEW. values.where department_id=department_id should probably be where department_id=NEW.department_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was pointed out by @P.Salmon, in general you shouldn't store data you can easily calculate. For this application, a [`VIEW`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html) (as suggested by @TamilSelvanC) is a good solution. For example:

```
CREATE VIEW departments_view AS
SELECT d.department_id, d.department_name, COUNT(e.employee_id) AS total_employees
FROM departments d
LEFT JOIN employees e ON e.department_name = d.department_name
GROUP BY d.department_id;
SELECT * FROM departments_view
```

Output:

```
department_id   department_name     total_employees
1               HRM                 3
2               Accounting          1
3               Engineering         0
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9c1945ff216f39f40e3e9a54d907e060)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, exact solution that I've been looking for. Hats off.

Comment: But it gives default value as 1, when number of employees in a department is 0. how can I get rid of this? would appreciate any sort of suggestions.

Comment: @Bappi_SB sorry about that - I hadn't considered that possibility in my demo. I've updated the query and the demo to give the correct answer when there are no employees in a department

Comment: Thanks a bunch Sir.